# How to draw data table that have list inside the list?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

So i want to draw a table to a data table, that have a list(list of grade) inside the list(list of student) that i want to draw, can i do that?if can, how to do it?

The object that is like :

```
 public class Student
    {
        public string No{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Grade_List> list_grade{ get; set; }

    }

    public class Grade_List
    {
        public string grade { get; set; }
        public string in_number{ get; set; }
    }
```

Code that i use for drawing is like :

```
$.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(DataQuery),
                    success: function (response) {
                        var total = 0;
                        $prodData.clear();
                        response.forEach(function (element, index) {
                            let No = index + 1;
                            //add object as a new table row
                            $prodData.row.add({
                                "No": No,
                                "Name": element.name,
                                "Grade": element.grade,
                                "In Number": element.in_number,

                            });
                        });
                        $prodData.draw(false);
                        alert("Success : Data has been loaded.");
                    }
                });
                });
```

I used this code for all of the table that dont have any list inside a list, but i dont know how to do it if have a list inside a list.

The table that i want to get is like :

```
No | Name | Grade | In Number
 1 | Ralph|   A   |    9
   |      |   C   |    6
   |      |   A   |    8
 2 | Andy |   B   |    7
   |      |   B   |    7
   |      |   A   |    8
```

Thank You.

Comment: You can flatten the data structure to make it simpler, but you can actually create a two level table so that when you click a row the row gets expanded. You can look into JQuery Datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an expandable row in your table you can take a look at this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). However, here's a more detailed version of thatexample. Assuming that you want to display information by expanding a row, you should first create an inner table (or a similar template which would be shown when the row is expanded).

The following code shows how you can do this in JavaScript:

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

Please keep in mind that instead of concatenating strings as displayed in this code you can simplify it by using the **`** character instead of **'** and use the the $ technique to render your template. However after you define the function that renders your inner table, you can bind it to a column in your table so that when the user clicks it the row would be expanded.

Since you need to decorate the corresponding column in a way that the use can simply figure out to click on it to expand the row, you should create a CSS class first and then bind it with one of the columns in your table.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );
```

The `details-control` class is an example of what I'm taking about here. After this step, you can bind an event to that class to respond to the user's action.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that you need JQuery DataTables to implement expandable row this way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Transcendent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54035101/10863059), if you just want to loop through all elements of list inside another list, easiest way to do it is just to add another forEach loop inside first forLoop:

```
    response.forEach(function (element, index) {
        let No = index + 1;
        element.list_grade.forEach(function (grade, new_index) {
            // GET GRADE VALUE LIKE THIS -> grade.grade
            // GET IN_NUMBER VALUE LIKE THIS -> grade.in_number
        }

        $prodData.row.add({
        ...
        });
    });
```